# Прямая речь начинается с имени собственного в кавычках

Tags: кавычки, цитата

Как оформлять кавычки, если прямая речь начинается с имени собственного в кавычках?
Пример:

«”Зарядье” — один из центров городской жизни столицы. Поэтому здесь пройдёт фестиваль уличной культуры, — отметил ... . — “Уличная классика” предлагает москвичам по-новому взглянуть на любимый город».

Обратите внимание на “Зарядье” и “Уличную классику”. Буду очень признательна за ответ!

Comment: Да. избегать надо такие ситуации по возможности: кавычки менять на курсив, не ставить слово в кавычках в начало фразы. Можно сказать:  Так "уличная классика"  предлагает...

Answer (score 1):

> — Парк «Зарядье» — один из центров городской жизни столицы, и здесь
> пройдёт фестиваль уличной культуры, — отметил N. — «Уличная классика»
> предложит москвичам по-новому взглянуть на любимый город.
>
> «В Парке "Зарядье", центре городской жизни столицы, пройдёт "Уличная
> классика" — фестиваль уличной культуры, — отметил N. — Он предложит
> москвичам по-новому взглянуть на любимый город».

Не будет ошибкой не брать в кавычки отдельное слово *Зарядье*, имея в виду исторический район Москвы. В вашем тексте они не нужны.